# Deleting a record from cassandra with just the date

Tags: python, database, cassandra, timestamp, cql

I have a usecase wherein I need write a script to purge a table in cassandra db for all data that is more than 90 days old.
Now the issue is that the DB has the eventdate (timestamp) in the below format:

```
2018-01-21 12:33:12+0000
```

From my script I have no way to get the exact timestamp: as in the hours minutes and seconds, and unless I have that the query is not picking up this data.

Can anyone suggest how can I select data from the table with only the date: yyyy-mm-dd.

Note: eventdate is a partition key for the table.
Also I am currently writing this script using python.

Update:
When I tried using token(eventdate):

```
SELECT * from solr_reports_table_v1 WHERE key1='test' and key2 = 'test' and key3='test' and token(eventdate) > '2018-01-20';
```

I get the below error:

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid STRING constant (2018-01-20) for "partition key token" of type bigint"
```

This is the eventdate field:

```
eventdate timestamp
```

Comment: It's better to change your code that inserts data to set TTL to 90 days, so data will be deleted automatically

Comment: We have existing data so that wont be possible

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to specify a range filter on a partition key. So, it is not possible to do things like

```
select * from mytable where eventdate > some_date_1 and eventdate < some_date_2
```

Also, simply selecting all rows and iterating over them won't work because when you get an exception, you cannot continue from the point you left.

Even though you cannot specify range filters on partition keys, you can specify range filters by using the [token function](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html) of CQL:

```
SELECT eventdate FROM mytable WHERE token(eventdate) >= start_token AND token(eventdate ) < end_token;
```

After each iteration, you should assign `end_token+1` to `start_token` and calculate the new `end_token`. You can also parallelize this by partitioning and sharing the whole token range into number of threads that run at the same time.

Comment: Tried that, getting an error, please see the update above in the question

Comment: token function will not return a date to you, it returns a bigint. You should pass through your entire token range to get all the rows. What is the structure of your table solr_reports_table_v1?